# What is a csdproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have inherited a C# Visual Studio solution.

There is a ProjectName.csdproj file as well as a ProjectName.csproj file.

What is a csdproj file? Do I need it? Can/should I delete it?

P.S. I really do mean csDproj. I know what csproj is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a smart device project from earlier releases of VS. I would guess that the .csproj is just the converted version of the same project. You can verify that with its content.

Keeping it around would mean someone is using VS2003 and later versions too. If not then keeping just the .csproj should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Removing it seems to have no effect.